# In Symfony, how can I use the url_for helper in a class?

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4, helper

I am building a URL inside of a class and I'd like to be able to change the routing if necessary later by just changing the routing.yml file.

If I have the route:

```
userSignup:
  url:   /user/signup
  param: { module: user, action: signup }
```

How can I use the **url_for('userSignup')** helper in a class to dynamically create the URL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use the view helpers in your action to generate a url:

```
$this->generateUrl("userSignup");
```

The method is defined in [sfComponent.class.php](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php#L211). This is the recommended way, not the hacky workaround of loading the view helpers and using them.

Answer (score 13):

I only tried this with 1.2 so I can't speak for any previous versions...

From any of your classes:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('Url'));
```

...then you can continue with using any of the functions defined in the url helper.

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm in 1.2.  But I do get --  The sfLoader::loadHelpers() method is deprecated. Please use the same method from sfApplicationConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
sfLoader::loadHelpers(array('Url'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use [`sfContext::getInstance()`](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/) to retrieve the configuration.

```
// instead of using
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Url');

// use 
sfApplicationConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('Url'));
```